# Prevent one user to get into other user's data

Tags: permissions, sudo, users, user-management

I have two users in the home directory (home/user1 and home/user2). I want them all to have all permissions but I don't want the second one to access data from user1. Both can read and install software but user2 cannot get into user1. I don't know how to manage this. Thanks.

Comment: If you enable encrypted user1 home directory **and** take a promise from user2 **under oath** not to use their "all permissions" to overcome that, then maybe :-) ... otherwise, if a user has "all permissions" the whatever you do; they can undo ... unless you put user1's home directory on an external drive and take the hard drive with you.

Comment: "I want them all to have all permissions" and "but I don't want the second one to access data from user1" is impossible as it is a contradiction:  "data from user1" is included in "all". Encrypting the directory is not an option: the data will be visible when decrypted.  The only way to prevent this is to NOT store user1 data on that system.

Comment: Oh, I see. The thing is I have to give an administrador credentials to install one package in my server, but, obviously, I don't want to give this person full access to my system. He needs an user to deploy this software, with permission to install, but I don't want him to access my main user.

Comment: If you can do "sudo apt install", you can take over a system. All a user would have to do is make their own .deb package with a malicious postinst script, then run it with "sudo apt install /path/to/hack.deb".

Answer (score 0):

Use virtualization. Make a separate virtual machine for each user, and let them both have total and complete root privileges *over their own VM.* They can do whatever they want in that VM, but they can't do a thing to the VM of the other user. How exactly you set this up will depend heavily on what your intended use case is, but one possibility would be to create two standard user accounts (no root or sudo privileges), each one with it's own GNOME Boxes VM. So long as you keep the system regularly updated, that should be sufficient (unless one user or the other comes up with a zero-day exploit that lets them break Linux access control mechanisms, but that's probably not a likely scenario).

Edit: Reading the comments, this solution probably won't work in your particular scenario, but it is a valid answer to the original question and might help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rethink what you are trying to achieve. Your stated requirements

1. "I want both users to have all permissions."
2. "I don't want the second one to access data from user1."

are contradictory.
Accessing data *is* a permission.
Consequently, if the second user has *all* permissions, that includes the permission to access data from user1.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Like I said in a previous answer I have to give an administrador credentials to install one package in my server, but, obviously, I don't want to give this person full access to my system. He needs an user to deploy this software, with permission to install, but I don't want him to access my main user. I don't want him to get data stored in the user1 directory. I just want him to be able of log in via SSH, deploy the software and leave. Which kind of permission does he need then? Or what can I do?

Comment: You can configure `/etc/sudoers` so that user2 can run the deploy command, but nothing else, with root privileges via `sudo` without a password. Of course you'll have to make sure that command cannot be abused for a general privilege escalation, so just allowing `sudo apt` without qualification is out of the question.